# Couchbase many to many relationship modeling

Tags: nosql, couchbase, data-modeling, relationships, sql++

I trying to figure out how to model my data - in a **many to many** relationship in Couchbase (im using n1ql as well).

I have two entities: **Clients** and **Projects**.

- Client - each client can create many projects - approximately 2000 projects per year.
- Project - each project can belong to many clients (maximum 50 clients).

I thought maybe creating a new document for each site/project, but according to Couchbase documentation on data modeling:

> This typically isn’t a good approach in Couchbase Server as
>   referencing and embedding provides a great deal of flexibility to
>   avoid creating this redundant document.

How should I store the data ?

Any suggestion/advice would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer following URL to resolve above issue: 
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/data-modeling/modeling-relationships.html

Comment: this is also nosql approach to resolve the above issue : http://blog.markstarkman.com/blog/2011/09/15/mongodb-many-to-many-relationship-data-modeling/

Answer (score 1):

That quote is referencing "relationship documents". In your case, that would mean you'd have a client document, a project document, and some sort of client-project mapping document. I would agree that a document *only* for a relationship would not be a useful approach, unless you intend to store a lot of information *about that relationship*.

Based on the information you've given, I'd recommend storing Client documents and Project documents. Based on the numbers, I'd say the projects should contain a list of Client document IDs.

Something like:

```
key client::001
{
   "name" : "Clienty McClientface",
   "address" : "123 main st",
   "foo" : "bar",
   "type" : "client"
}

key project::001
{
    "name" : "Alan Parsons Project",
    "startDate" : "2012-09-27",
    "clients" : [
        "client::001",
        "client::007",
        "client::123",
        // ... etc ...
    ],
    "type" : "project"
}
```

But in general, it depends on what your use cases are for reads, writes, queries. No data model will fit every use case.